# Installing dlib on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, dlib

I've had trouble installing dlib, specifically the python verson, on my heroku app.  I compiled everything fine on my local machine but when I push dlib.so and the build directory to heroku, whenever I try importing I get `ImportError: libboost_python-py27.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.  I made sure that `dlib.so` is in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you solve you problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dlib requires boost which can be hard to install successfully, as you have discovered.

The rule of thumb is to use Heroku Buildpacks to install such libraries.
To install Dlib, go to your Heroku dashboard, settings and click on Add Buildpack.

Depending on your python version you can use any of the two Buildpacks below;

For python 2.7.13

```
https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku14-buildpack-python-opencv-dlib.git
```

For python 3.6.1

```
https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku16-buildpack-python-opencv-dlib.git
```

Comment: That's false Davis King. You need Boost, CMake and X11. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/

Comment: X11 is optional and CMake is trivial to install.

Comment: Trivial or not, it is a dependency.

Comment: You might as well list GCC, disk drivers, an OS kernel, etc. as dependencies then.

Comment: My research: How to install dlib by Adrian Rosebrock  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/.

Step #1: Install dlib prerequisites

The dlib library only has four primary prerequisites:

Boost: ...
Boost.Python: As the name of this library suggests, Boost.Python provides interoperability between the C++ and Python programming language.
CMake: ...
X11/XQuartx: ...

Comment: My research:  I wrote dlib :)

Comment: I did my research, I demand you upvote my answer which you downvoted. Moreover, I suggested  using a Buildpack as a solution

Comment: Great work with Dlib sir but I don't think you were fair downvoting my answer. I did provide a solution using Buildpacks.

Comment: There you go.  Although I will point out that the OP already has CMake installed.  Their issue is almost certainly related to mixing different versions of python.  This is a common dlib FAQ: http://dlib.net/faq.html#WhywontthePythonbindingscompilework

Comment: Well, that or they have somehow partially installed boost and simply have their LD_LIBRARY_PATH wrong and it just doesn't find boost.  Although it's hard to say from what they posted.  Really they should try to put that boost .so file into their LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Thanks. I see, I  have a currently have a similar issue, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622227/how-can-i-install-dlib-in-a-heroku-python-web-app-using-requirements-txt. I will really appreciate your assistance, I've been stuck on this for almost a week now. I used python-3.6.1

Comment: Davis King please could you spare sometime to help me out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622227/how-can-i-install-dlib-in-a-heroku-python-web-app-using-requirements-txt

Comment: @Nuelsian the solution didn't make any difference for me, did I do something wrong? I just added your link on Heroku and then pushed again.

Comment: Trying to install dlib @ Rodrigo Ruiz? You're better of using Python anywhere to build python web apps or apis.

Comment: So I tried installing appbuild pack using the link you provided and I got this error: This does not look like a tar archive
remote: xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now