# How can I install Dlib in a Heroku python web app using requirements.txt?

Tags: python, opencv, heroku, boost, dlib

I built a Python Flask web API that involves machine learning and I've had a lot of frustration deploying it on Heroku.

The problem is, my app has a dependency on Dlib ( a library) and I can't seem to find a way to install in my Heroku server. I'm losing my mind trying to fix this and I can imagine other AI developers out there who might encounter this problem. Please help me

**Here is what I have done so far.**

I have tried not using a Buildpack by specifying dlib==19.4.0 along with its dependencies in my requirements.txt but It fails due to a dependency on Boost.

I have researched on the dependency for Dlib (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/);

```
build-essential cmake  # I already have this in my requirements.txt
libgtk-3-dev
libboost-all-dev
```

Also,

```
numpy  # I already have this in my requirements.txt
scipy  # I already have this in my requirements.txt
sciKit-Image  # I already have this in my requirements.txt
```

So I included boost==0.1, cmake==0.7.1 & boost-py==1.00 in my requirements.txt file.
The installation failed, here's the **build log**

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.2 (you are using python-3.6.1, which is unsupported).
 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.2).
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.6.1
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting gunicorn (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
       Collecting boost==0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading boost-0.1.tar.gz
       Collecting boost-py==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading boost_py-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting click==6.7 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
       Collecting cmake==0.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 5))
         Downloading cmake-0.7.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.1MB)
       Collecting colorthief==0.2.1 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading colorthief-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting cycler==0.10.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting Flask==0.12.2 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 8))
         Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
       Collecting Flask-Gunicorn==0.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 9))
         Downloading Flask_Gunicorn-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting imutils==0.4.3 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 10))
         Downloading imutils-0.4.3.tar.gz
       Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 11))
         Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
       Collecting Jinja2==2.9.6 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 12))
         Downloading Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
       Collecting jsonify==0.5 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 13))
         Downloading jsonify-0.5.tar.gz
       Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 14))
         Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
       Collecting matplotlib==2.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 15))
         Downloading matplotlib-2.0.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.6MB)
       Collecting numpy==1.13.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 16))
         Downloading numpy-1.13.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.0MB)
       Collecting olefile==0.44 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 17))
         Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB)
       Collecting opencv-python==3.2.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 18))
         Downloading opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.7MB)
       Collecting Pillow==4.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 19))
         Downloading Pillow-4.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.7MB)
       Collecting pymongo==3.4.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 20))
         Downloading pymongo-3.4.0.tar.gz (583kB)
       Collecting pyparsing==2.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 21))
         Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
       Collecting python-dateutil==2.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 22))
         Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
       Collecting pytz==2017.2 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 23))
         Downloading pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484kB)
       Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 24))
         Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting Werkzeug==0.12.2 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 25))
         Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
       Collecting dlib==19.7.0 (from -r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 26))
         Downloading dlib-19.7.0.tar.gz (4.0MB)
       Collecting Mastodon.py (from boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading Mastodon.py-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting sqlalchemy (from boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.1.14.tar.gz (5.2MB)
       Collecting peppercorn (from boost-py==1.0.0->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading peppercorn-0.5.tar.gz
       Collecting requests (from Mastodon.py->boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
       Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->Mastodon.py->boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
       Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->Mastodon.py->boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
       Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->Mastodon.py->boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (349kB)
       Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->Mastodon.py->boost==0.1->-r /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
       Installing collected packages: gunicorn, urllib3, idna, certifi, chardet, requests, six, python-dateutil, pytz, Mastodon.py, sqlalchemy, boost, peppercorn, boost-py, click, cmake, olefile, Pillow, colorthief, cycler, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, Flask, Flask-Gunicorn, imutils, jsonify, pyparsing, numpy, matplotlib, opencv-python, pymongo, dlib
         Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: started
           Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for boost: started
           Running setup.py install for boost: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for peppercorn: started
           Running setup.py install for peppercorn: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for olefile: started
           Running setup.py install for olefile: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: started
           Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
           Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for imutils: started
           Running setup.py install for imutils: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for jsonify: started
           Running setup.py install for jsonify: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for pymongo: started
           Running setup.py install for pymongo: finished with status 'done'
         Running setup.py install for dlib: started
           Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
           Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-377kpsyp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
           running install
           running build
           Detected Python architecture: 64bit
           Detected platform: linux
           Configuring cmake ...
           -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
           -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
           -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
           -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
           -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
           -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
           -- Detecting C compile features
           -- Detecting C compile features - done
           -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
           -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
           -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
           -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
           -- Detecting CXX compile features
           -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
             Imported targets not available for Boost version
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1536 (message):
             No header defined for python-py34; skipping header check
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           -- Could NOT find Boost
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
             Imported targets not available for Boost version
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:63 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1536 (message):
             No header defined for python-py35; skipping header check
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:63 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           -- Could NOT find Boost
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
             Imported targets not available for Boost version
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:66 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1536 (message):
             No header defined for python3; skipping header check
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:66 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           -- Could NOT find Boost
           CMake Warning at /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
             Imported targets not available for Boost version
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:869 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1472 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
             /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:69 (FIND_PACKAGE)
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           -- Could NOT find Boost
           -- Found PythonLibs: /tmp/build_910a6f43d62d0d69b0d944c5ae4b3c87/Nuelsian-deployment-0ffa4db157435edabc6f7cb904da61e2379ac163/.heroku/python/lib/libpython3.6m.a (found suitable version "3.6.1", minimum required is "3.4")
           --  *****************************************************************************************************
           --  To compile Boost.Python yourself download boost from boost.org and then go into the boost root folder
           --  and run these commands:
           --     ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
           --     ./b2
           --     sudo ./b2 install
           --  *****************************************************************************************************
           CMake Error at /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:116 (message):
              Boost python library not found.
           Call Stack (most recent call first):
             CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
           -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
           See also "/tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
           error: cmake configuration failed!

           ----------------------------------------
       Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-377kpsyp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yongtg64/dlib/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I also tried using the Heroku Buildpack, https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku16-buildpack-python3-opencv-dlib.git and https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku114-buildpack-python3-opencv-dlib.git 
It's almost as if Heroku skipped my requirements.txt and only tried installing the Buildpacks.

**Here's the Log file:**

```
-----> Python3 + OpenCV + DLib app detected
-----> Generating environment
       Fetching...
       Unpacking...
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
-----> Found requirements.txt, installing dependencies using pip
/app/tmp/buildpacks/6c499595b704aea0287ed02dc4cb12382496a45391b9e41bdf4fe9d946bbf725b480741dac04e7f02dbb412489937b86a1837abdc27865b9b20adfce0b360eef/bin/compile: line 78: /app/.heroku/vendor/bin/pip3: No such file or directory
-----> Creating environment variables.
-----> Buildpack installed.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 185.4M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://magicmirrordotai.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

When I then open the app, I get the **Application error** with log;

```
2017-10-07T12:33:47.122379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --log-file -`
2017-10-07T12:33:49.627779+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2017-10-07T12:33:49.700534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2017-10-07T12:33:49.713288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
```

I observed that if I deploy the app without including these Buildpacks I get no error with gunicorn, but I need dlib for my app.

My **requirements.txt file:**

```
gunicorn
click==6.7
cmake==0.7.1
colorthief==0.2.1
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Gunicorn==0.1.1
imutils==0.4.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
jsonify==0.5
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
numpy==1.13.0
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.2.0.7
Pillow==4.1.1
pymongo==3.4.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

My **runtime.txt**

```
python-3.6.1
```

My **Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file -
```

Comment: Can someone please help me out. @David King

Comment: did u solve this? i want to know too!

Comment: I moved to Pythonanywhere. It was super easy and intuitive installing all my app's dependencies as I do on my computer. I initially hesitated using python anywhere because setting up my app exceeded my free 512mb storage space but seeing I had no other alternative especially after my ordeal with Heroku I decided to pay, so I am now a paid user of Python anywhere. I am currently subscribed to their $5 a month plan.

Comment: Next time when you see a question you would also like to have an answer to upvote it!  This enables it get more views and makes it more likely to be answered. This question only has 58 views as of now (25/10/2017), this is after several weeks of my posting it and I contributed to more than 40 views to it. I can't help sounding pissed, I am. I spent about two months just trying to deploy an application that took me about 4 months to build.

Comment: With the most recent update to Dlib, addling Dlib to your buildpack shouldn't be a problem anymore as the Boost dependency has been removed https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/293

Comment: we have the same issue, have you solved this? I'm using `Google Cloud` not heroku. And `dlib` seems to be not working when included in `requirements.txt`

Comment: I migrated to pythonanywhere

Answer (score 0):

With the most recent update to Dlib, addling Dlib to your buildpack shouldn't be a problem anymore as the Boost dependency has been removed https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/293

Comment: So I tried installing dlib appbuild pack using the link: https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku16-buildpack-python3-opencv-dlib.git and I got this error: This does not look like a tar archive remote: xz: (stdin): File format not recognized remote: tar: Child returned status 1 remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Answer (score 0):

You need cmake to install dlib. To install cmake in heroku you need to buildpack cmake and set that build in order to install dlib.

You can use this buildpack for cmake
[heroku-buildpack-cmake](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/vovchikmonkey/heroku-buildpack-cmake)

**Do this in your CLI**

1. Login to heroku
2. copy paste `heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/VovchikMonkey/heroku-buildpack-cmake.git`
3. And finally set the buildpack `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/Starkast/heroku-buildpack-cmake`
4. And then deploy
   `$ git add . 
   $ git commit -am "make it better" 
   $ git push heroku` master